# Issues with npm after running 'npm install -g @vue/cli'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, vue-cli

TIA for your help as I'm a beginner working with node and Vue.

I had been working with Vue 2 so I tried to update the version by running 'npm install -g @vue/cli' via command line. However, after I ran the command, I got these messages:
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What went wrong with the 'npm install -g @vue/cli' command and how can I fix this?

When I check node -v and nvm -v it runs just fine, but npm and vue for some reason are no longer recognized. I rebooted my computer a few times, changed the environment variable from other stack overflow advices, but nothing worked and I'm out of solutions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , it's unknown what's your environment. Is it windows or linux? "nvm" is relatively exotic and the problem is likely specific to it. The question is unrelated to vue. If you have a problem with running "npm", that's the problem. It looks like a coincidence that this happened after npm install. Try to reinstall node with nvm, or get rid of nvm and install node from scratch.